# Suspend problems - Chromebook running 12.04.1 LTS

Tags: power-management, suspend, chromebook

I've been running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS for a few days now on my Acer C7 Chromebook - and in general it's running great.

However, I've noticed that when I try to suspend one of various things can happen:

1. Sometimes everything is fine.
2. Sometimes it doesn't enter suspend and I take my laptop out of my
   bag to find it roasting hot - not good!.
3. Sometimes when I open the lid again it performs a complete reboot -
   losing all my work! Also, not good!.

Basically, it leaves me in a position of uncertainty about closing my laptop without powering it down and saving all my work!

Can someone please provide me with some help, resources to help or pointers to looking into the problems.

Thanks very much, I really want to get on board with Ubuntu - other than this my experience has been great - but this is a major problem for me at the moment.

EDIT: Here are some more observations:
When I click on 'Suspend' (under the top right 'gear/cog' icon in Ubuntu) the laptop correctly enters suspend mode and the orange light starts to pulse.

If I wait a few moments (just to ensure that suspend starts correctly) and then press a keyboard key the suspend light turns blue.. and then off. The laptop has now completely powered down.

It appears it enters suspend okay but then dies when trying to resume.

Really need this to work as currently Ubuntu is useless for me as a portable OS without suspend/resume.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that touching the track pad while in suspend will cause the machine to start back up.

I also discovered that pressing on the machine in the touchpad area while the machine is closed causes the touchpad to be 'touched'.  This is likely why your machine comes out of your bag in an active state.  It was for me, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the TPM module:

```
modprobe tpm_tis force=1 interrupts=0
```

I was having a very similar [issue on my Chromebook Pixel](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=221905):

> The reset in this case is happening because the TPM resume command (actually TPM_Startup(ST_STATE)) is failing.